# sonata_type_datetime_picker Initial date

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin, bootstrap-datepicker

Now, when the date input is empty and I will fire datepicker, it will give me current datetime. I want to change this configuration to get current date but with time 00:00:00. I don't know how to get this. Any ideas?

I know that I have this options in creation of datepicker:

```
"action", "attr", "auto_initialize", "block_name", "by_reference", "cascade_validation", "compound", "constraints", "csrf_field_name", "csrf_message", "csrf_protection", "csrf_provider", "data", "data_class", "date_format", "date_widget", "datepicker_use_button", "days", "disabled", "dp_days_of_week_disabled", "dp_default_date", "dp_disabled_dates", "dp_enabled_dates", "dp_icons", "dp_language", "dp_max_date", "dp_min_date", "dp_minute_stepping", "dp_pick_time", "dp_show_today", "dp_side_by_side", "dp_use_current", "dp_use_minutes", "dp_use_seconds", "dp_use_strict", "empty_data", "empty_value", "error_bubbling", "error_mapping", "extra_fields_message", "format", "horizontal_input_wrapper_class", "horizontal_label_class", "horizontal_label_offset_class", "hours", "inherit_data", "input", "intention", "invalid_message", "invalid_message_parameters", "label", "label_attr", "label_render", "mapped", "max_length", "method", "minutes", "model_timezone", "months", "pattern", "post_max_size_message", "property_path", "read_only", "required", "seconds", "sonata_admin", "sonata_field_description", "sonata_help", "time_widget", "translation_domain", "trim", "validation_groups", "view_timezone", "virtual", "widget", "with_minutes", "with_seconds", "years"
```

I tried to use "dp_default_date", but it fills empty input on page refresh. "hours" and "minutes" don't work.

Comment: can you show your formMapper : I mean the datetime attribute in formMapper i think that you missed the format option.

Comment: Yep, this is it: 

            $formMapper->add('end_date', 'sonata_type_datetime_picker', array('required' => false, 'format' => 'dd.MM.yyyy, HH:mm:ss'))

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I fix the initial date by this way

```
->add('dateOfBirth', 'sonata_type_date_picker', array(
                'label' => 'Birthdate',
                'dp_default_date' => '01-1975',
                'datepicker_use_button' => false,
            ))
```

List of options available here

```
sonata-project/core-bundle/Form/Type/DateTimePickerType.php
```

and

```
sonata-project/core-bundle/Form/Type/BasePickerType.php
```

Answer (score 0):

You can then override the datetime picker user by sonata in vendor\sonata-project\core-bundle\Resources\views\Form you will find datepicker.html.twig so copy the file and put it under \app\Resources\views\Form and this script to the block sonata_type_date_picker_widget :

```
{% block sonata_type_date_picker_widget %}
{% spaceless %}
        {% if datepicker_use_button %}
            <div class='input-group date datepicker' id='{{ id }}' data-date-autoclose="true" data-date-format="dd/mm/yyyy">
            {% else %}
                {% set attr = attr|merge({'data-date-format': moment_format}) %}
            {% endif %}
            {{ block('date_widget') }}
            {% if datepicker_use_button %}
                <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></span>
            </div>
        {% endif %}
  //Script to add//
    <script type="text/javascript">
        (function ($) {
            $.fn.datepicker.dates['fr'] = {
                days: ["Dimanche", "Lundi", "Mardi", "Mercredi", "Jeudi", "Vendredi", "Samedi", "Dimanche"],
                daysShort: ["Dim.", "Lun.", "Mar.", "Mer.", "Jeu.", "Ven.", "Sam.", "Dim."],
                daysMin: ["D", "L", "Ma", "Me", "J", "V", "S", "D"],
                months: ["Janvier", "Février", "Mars", "Avril", "Mai", "Juin", "Juillet", "Août", "Septembre", "Octobre", "Novembre", "Décembre"],
                monthsShort: ["Janv.", "Févr.", "Mars", "Avril", "Mai", "Juin", "Juil.", "Août", "Sept.", "Oct.", "Nov.", "Déc."],
                today: "Aujourd'hui",
                clear: "Effacer",
                weekStart: 1,
                format: "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss"
            };
        }(jQuery));
        jQuery(function ($) {
            $('#{{ id }}').datepicker({
                language: 'fr',
                format: "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss"

            });


        });
    </script>
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock sonata_type_date_picker_widget %}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! Hmm, i can't see anything which should resolve my problem. Where is the line of code which makes that thing which I need? This JS only change language and format - I don't need this.